# Create a Data Set of strings that stores string value, frequency in set and time

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to create a Stream Graph DATA SET from a Twitter feed.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to store a string and its count but I need to display the frequency over time so I also need to store when each instance of the word occurred so I can plot it.

What would be the best database structure and query that would allow me to quickly store the string values, count and date and the pull that into an array?

What I'm thinking of doing is having one large Table that stores all the text values and their dates.

Then I am going to run a query on the full Table to find the top 5 words in ALL rows and their counts and store that in another Table.

Then I'm going to run another query on the full Table and pull the count of the top 5 words sort by Date.

Any suggestions for ways to improve this or some easy LINQ or SQL queries that might help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Without diving into detail (which I'd like to do on this one, sounds fun)... I'd just make sure that first of all you're thinking in terms of storing the resulting time series measures in OLAP schema... fact tables and dimensions and all that.  Data models for reporting are completely different than for transactional systems.

Comment: I had to look up OLAP, seems like that would be a good approach. My application is a one off solution, but I'm here to learn.